# event handling in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to know the how to handle when user press up arrow when focused on a textbox

Comment: And what've you tried..?

Comment: My apologies, but I have no idea what you meant in your comment..?

Comment: i mean to say how i know keycode of up arrow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("input_selector").focus(function(){
    $(this).bind("keyup", function(e){
         if ( e.keyCode == 39){
              //do what you want with the up arrow
         }
    });
});

$("input_selector").blur(function(){
    $(this).unbind("keyup");
});
```

Comment: Is there a reason for having the handler only when the textbox is focused?

Comment: Yes because the question was "when user press up arrow when focused on a textbox" and you wouldn't want the execute the same code for the keyup when you are not focused on a textfield.

Comment: question specifically asks for it

Comment: But a keyup event on a textbox only fires when it has focus in the first place.

Comment: @Matti Virkkunen Im pretty sure if the corner is clicked on and the dotted outline is present (FF only) it can still accept the keyup event. Regardless for me its just good housekeeping. I know when the events will fire 100% of the time and I get rid of them if I don't need them.

Answer (score 2):

You can grab the event itself by binding to the [keyup](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/) event with jQuery.  As for determining which key was pressed, [here's a quick little tutorial](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/javascriptkey2.shtml) on key codes in JavaScript.  You can adapt this code to check against the key being pressed in the event.

They key code you're looking for (the up arrow) is `38`.

Answer (score 1):

See the documentation for [keyboard events](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/keyboard-events/) in jQuery

Answer (score 1):

See this [Keypress Event](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/)